# Android OnItemClickListener and OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-activity, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

1. Is in a custom array adapter class (getView method)
2. Is in an activity class (onCreate method) Expressionless face

What is the difference please?

[1. 1st Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpKe8.png)

[2. 2nd Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd8e8.png)

Comment: Consider adding the code as part of the question instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

OnClick is on a view, which is invoked when the user clicks on it.

OnItemClick is on an adapter which manages a virtual list, and when the user clicks on the 'view' which the content is managed by the adapter, the adapter is responsible for figuring out which item it is in the dataset it manages was clicked, and invoking the that.

OnItemClickListener will provide you information like the position in the adapter and the ID it manages for that item
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener